# Attribute Name overlapping in setattribute property of Xelement

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument

I am trying to re-build an XMI structure. So for that i need to append a child node like below

```
 <node xmi:type="shape" xmi:id="12358" type="rectangle">
 </node >
```

So created an **XMLElement** and tried to add attributes using below code

```
 XmlElement child= papNotdoc.CreateElement("node");
 child.SetAttribute("type", "http://www.omg.org/XMI", "Shape");
 child.SetAttribute("id", "http://www.omg.org/XMI","12358");
 child.SetAttribute("type", "rectangle");
```

using the namespace URL so that i will get a prefix **XMI:** in one of the **type** attribute.

But unfortunately XML element treats both type named attributes as same attributes and giving me an output as below

```
 <node xmi:type="rectangle" xmi:id="12358">
 </node >
```

I want both the **xmi:type** and **type** attribute in a node.How to achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give `null` to namespaceURI param of `SetAttribute` method.

```
XmlElement child = papNotdoc.CreateElement("node");
child.SetAttribute("type", "http://www.omg.org/XMI", "Shape");
child.SetAttribute("id", "http://www.omg.org/XMI", "12358");
child.SetAttribute("type", null, "rectangle");
```

Comment: Are you sure about that ? Because added another one with default prefix name.